# Kohana I18n __() or maybe I18n::load(). Performance

Tags: php, html, kohana, translation, multilingual

If I have medium multilingual page and I have to translate all short sentence on this page (i.e. 'Create account' etc), how much time takes usually translation? Is time of translation perceptible for users?

And the second question, has

```
$array = I18n::load('lang-lang')
```

and the using it better performance then just using __()?

Comment: Benchmark it and you'll know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__()` is a proxy to [strtr()](http://php.net/strtr), which is a native PHP function, meaning very fast.

With 150 strings you won't notice any performance changes without a benchmark (meaning 0.00x s for translations total).

I don't understand the other part of the question as `I18n::load()` isn't comparable to `__()` at all, it just loads the appropriate translations file.

Comment: Thanks for response. 
I mean, when I use load() it loads file once, and what happens if I use __(), each time script have to search whole file to find right translation?

Comment: @Mr Sooul: each translation array is loaded only once